# What does the coordinate values represent when using WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, accuracy, mercator

I have been using QGIS for a couple of weeks now, mostly for data collection in my research project. Currently, I'm trying to plot these points,

[image]

in a graph similar to this one (but in kilometers),

[image]

I have extracted the coordinate values provided by the CRS WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857)(default projection when using OSM), but I cannot figure out what they represent. I would guess that it's the distance from equator and Greenwhich but when I compute these distances myself the result is off by hundreds km along the x axis (actual distance 414,18 km) and thousand km along the y axis (actual distance 5625,06 km).

[image]

Now, there is two options. Either the projection distorts the distance between points around the globe by a really large amount or the axis used are not lat_0=0 and long_0=0.

Which one is it then,or is there something else that I'm missing ?

Comment: Distortion is correct. See https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-web-Mercator-projection_fig5_298354278.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection for more detailed description/explanation of Mercator projection and its distortion of sizes.